# Deploying Django using Nginx Docker Container

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, devops

***Situation:*** I have a Django Application that I want to deploy, the tools I use for this one are Nginx, Gunicorn, and all of them are inside a docker container using Docker Desktop.

***Problem:*** I'm able to view the django app locally using the IP of my docker, IP of my machine, and Loopback IP. However when I try to access it from my laptop(another machine connected on same wifi), I can't access it.

***My Machine:*** Windows 10, I have already enable the expose of port 80 in the windows firewall inbound and outbound.

***Steps Taken:*** I've tried doing python -m http.server 80 on my machine, and it's working perfectly fine so I'm sure there is something to do maybe on my Hyper-V of docker desktop or maybe nginx configuration

My docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:

  dashboard:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/dashboard/src
      - static_volume:/opt/services/dashboard/src/static
    networks:  # <-- here
      - nginx_network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:80:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_volume:/opt/services/dashboard/src/static
    depends_on:
      - dashboard
    networks:  # <-- here
      - nginx_network

networks:  # <-- and here
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  static_volume:  # <-- declare the static volume
```

My dockerfile

```
# start from an official image
FROM python:3.6

# arbitrary location choice: you can change the directory
RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/dashboard/src
WORKDIR /opt/services/dashboard/src

# install our two dependencies
RUN pip install gunicorn django requests jira python-dateutil

# copy our project code
COPY . /opt/services/dashboard/src

# expose the port 80
EXPOSE 80

# define the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":80", "dashboard.wsgi:application"]
```

My nginx config file

```
# first we declare our upstream server, which is our Gunicorn application
upstream dashboard_server {
    # docker will automatically resolve this to the correct address
    # because we use the same name as the service: "djangoapp"
    server dashboard:80;
}

# now we declare our main server
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # everything is passed to Gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://dashboard_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/services/dashboard/src/static/;
    }
}
```

Here is an image of my folder structure.
[Image of folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkPne.png)

**QUESTION:** How do I atleast make it viewable on my laptop which is connected through the same Wifi as my desktop machine? I've tried accesing it using the IP of my machine.

Comment: You say you "can't access it" from your laptop connected to the same network. What URL did you try? You should go to the local IP of the machine running the web app, something like 192.168.0.X, where X is between 2 and 253 (254?).

Comment: I've edited the Question section, yes I've tried to access it using the IP. I'm using docker desktop btw, I was thinking maybe I need to set up the network of it?

Comment: Is it working when you access the URL from the local machine?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm thinking maybe it's a problem with the NAT of Hyper-V? it's a possibility. but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Why did you comment the EXPOSE 80 in the Dockerfile? The dashboard service needs the port 80 to be exposed no?

Comment: my mistake, I already Uncomented it.

Comment: @pawamoy any idea on this one? :/

Comment: I think we need more information. When you say that you "can't access it", what is your browser showing? What IP are you using as URL? How did you get it? You're mentioning NAT or Hyper-V, which I'm totally not familiar with, so I'm afraid I can't really help ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted the router switch and it worked perfectly.